# SVD Latex representation

Tags: matrices

[image]

How can I create the SVD representation as shown in the image using latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can see the `blkarray` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code with `blkarray`:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}

        \usepackage{amsmath} 
        \usepackage{bigstrut} 
        \usepackage{blkarray}

        \begin{document}

        \[
        \bigstrutjot=0.8ex\begin{blockarray}{cccc}%
             & &|V| \\
        \begin{block}{c[ccc]}
         \bigstrut[t] \\ |V| & & X & \\ \bigstrut \\
        \end{block}
        \end{blockarray}
        = \begin{blockarray}{ccc@{\:}c}%
             & &|V| \\
        \begin{block}{c[cc@{\:}c]}
       &{} \mid{}\bigstrut[t] & \vert \\ |V| & u_1 & u_2 & \dotsb \\ & \vert & \vert\bigstrut \\
        \end{block}
        \end{blockarray}
       \begin{blockarray}{cccc}%
             & &|V| \\
        \begin{block}{c[cc@{\:}c]}
       & \sigma_1 & 0 & \dotsb \bigstrut[t] \\ |V| & 0 & \sigma_2 & \dotsb \\ & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
        \end{blockarray}
       \begin{blockarray}{cc@{\:}cc}%
             & &|V| \\
        \begin{block}{c[c@{\enspace}c@{\:}c]}
       & {}\relbar & v_1 & \relbar\bigstrut[t] \\ |V| & {}\relbar & v_2 & \relbar \\ & & \vdots &\bigstrut[b] \\
        \end{block}
        \end{blockarray}
         \]

        \end{document}
```

[image]